# SWIFT how to sort a dictionary without creating a new one using collection functions?

Tags: swift, sorting, dictionary, collections

I have a homework where I must sort the following dictionary using collection functions without creating a new dictionary in SWIFT. How is that possible?

Here is my dictionary:

```
var mountains:[String:Int] = ["Mount Everest":8868,  "K2":8611,  "Kangchenjunga":8586,  "Lhotse":8516,  "Makalu":8485]
```

At the moment I am using the following code, but the code generates a new dictionary which is not allowed. I need to sort the dictionary itself?

```
    let sortedDictDesc = mountains.sorted { $1.1 < $0.1 }
```

Comment: Dictionary has no order

Comment: Maybe you have misunderstood the assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary can not be sorted by default in Swift. So if you sort it and try to retrieve it again, it will follow the fastest path. So I'm not sure why you need to return it without creating a type that is sortable.

If you really want to sort this you have various options like tuples or structs, but all of these require you to create a new property. You could always set your mountains to one of these different types though and then re-assign it.

Comment: Thanks I think I have misunderstood the assignment I will sort the dictionary using a new one as I did thanks to all!